# Ajuda com Jquery não aparece

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com um problema em meu site , tive a ajuda de um membro do fórum que me passou um código jquery , coloquei ele pra rodar em meu site só que estou com um problema com ele o aviso que deve ser gerado não aparece, alguem podeira me ajudar ? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo2etrelas2.png);
 border-left:1px solid #000;
 border-right:1px solid #000; 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 margin:auto;
 

}


#fundoinicial {
 background: #FFF;
 width: 1024px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 
}

#mapa {
 position:absolute;
 width: 660px;
 top:250px;
 left: 181px;
 
 
}

#lugares {
 position: absolute;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 top: 500px;
 left: 851px;
}

#cep label{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 height: 20px;
 top: 362px;
 left: 780px;
 
}

#cep button{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 height: 21px;
 width: 71px;
 top: 358px;
 left: 1028px;
 padding: 0px 3px;
 background: #60365E;
 border-bottom: none;
 color: #FFF;
 border-radius:10px;
  
  
  
 
}
#cep input{
 position: absolute;
 width: 112px;
 top: 359px;
 left: 911px;
 height: 15px;
 border-radius:10px;
}

#cep p1{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 109px;
 top: 388px;
 left: 854px;
}



#menufundo {
 background:#60365e;
 border:1px solid #000;
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:28px;
 margin:auto;
  
}


#ul li a{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-style:normal;
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 font-size:19px;
 line-height:0px;
 padding:10px;
    margin:4px 0 0 52px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:left;
 
 
}

#ul li a:hover{
 text-shadow:0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black; 
 font-size:19px;
    color:black;
}


.rodape {
 background: url(../imagens/rodape.png);
 margin: auto;
 position:absolute;
 width: 1056px;
 height: 99px;
 left: 132px;
 top: 704px;

 
 
}
 


h1 a{
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 175px;
 top: 716px;
 
}

p a{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 175px;
 top: 743px;
}

.facebook{
 width: 32px;
 right: 32px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: 515px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 
}

.facebook:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.trabalhe {
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 986px;
 top: 729px;
 width: 159px;

}

.email {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 20px;
 left: 987px;
 top: 732px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/ico.png" type="imagem/x-png" />
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilocobertura.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js" ></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(imagens/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var ceps = ['88000-000', '99000-000'], //array com os ceps válidos
   aviso = $('p');
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){ //função para quando clicar no botão
    cepDigitado = $('#cep').val(); //pega o valor do cep digitado
      aviso.html(''); //limpa o aviso
      
    if (ceps.indexOf(cepDigitado) > -1) { //verifica se o cep é válido
      aviso.html('CEP Válido!');
     } else {
      aviso.html('CEP Inválido!');
     }
  });

});


</script>
</head>


<body>


<div id="topo"></div><!--div final topo-->
<div id="menufundo">

<nav id="ul">    
          <ul>            
           <li><a href="index.html" title="Página Inicial">Página Inicial</a></li> 
           <li><a href="quem_somos.html" title="Quem Somos">Quem Somos</a></li>
           <li><a href="cobertura.html" title="Áreas de Cobertura">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li> 
           <li><a href="servicos.html" title="Serviços">Serviços</a></li>
           <li><a href="fale_conosco.html" title="Fale Conosco">Fale Conosco</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>
</div>

         
<div id ="fundoinicial">

<div id="mapa">
<img  src="imagens/mapa.jpg"  />
</div>
<div id="lugares">
<img src="imagens/lugares.jpg" />

</div>
</div>
<div id="cep">
  <label>Consulte Seu CEP:</label>
       <input type="text" id="cep" />
 <button>Pesquisar</button>
 <p></p>
</div>

</div>


<div class="rodape">
  
  
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Alfatec-Autorizada-Electrolux-1737242946511224/" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
  <img id= "facebook"  src="imagens/facebook-logo (2).png" alt="FaceBook" width="24" class="facebook" > 
  </a>
  
  
</div>








<h1><a href="maps" target="_blank" title="Abrir Mapa">Localização</a></h1>
<p><a href="maps" target="_blank" title="Abrir Mapa">R. Profᵃ José Azevedo Minhoto, 206<br />
Osasco - SP, 06080-125</a></p2>

<div class="trabalhe" > <h2>Trabalhe Conosco</h2></div>
<div class="email" > <p>rhalfatec@alfatec.com</p></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: essa validação do cep funciona?

Comment: Sim Funciona !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a biblioteca jquery.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> **OBS:** o aviso está sendo mostrado em todas as tags   `<p>` do seu documento.

Para evitar isso ao invés de usar  `aviso = $('p');` no seu script  use uma classe como por exemplo   `aviso = $('.paviso');`

e no HTML    `<p class="paviso"></p>`

> **Outra OBS:**  Um seletor ID de determinado nome só pode ser definido a UM e somente UM elemento HTML dentro do documento.

No seu documento temos `<div id="cep">` e `<input type="text" id="cep" />` com mesmo nome de id. Voce não pode definir mais de um elemento com o mesmo id em uma pagina.

```
<div id="cep">
<label>Consulte Seu CEP:</label>
                <input type="text" id="cep" />
```

Na verdade você até pode definir, porém segundo minhas experiencias tudo relacionado a esse id somente vai ter efeito sobre o primeiro elemento com esse nome de id.

No seu caso o script que pega o valor do elemento de id com nome cep vai atuar sobre a div (que está antes do input) e não sobre o input e consequentemente seu script não vai funcionar como desejado.

Se a div estivesse depois do input, seu script funcionaria!!

Comment: consegui Resolver dessa forma Muito Obrigado pela ajuda !!! Abs